# Android committing environment changes?

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I am developing Android app using Eclipse. I use Git also.

Occasionally, when I do `git status`, I see unstaged changes, although I did not actually do anything. These changes are probably done by Eclipse itself. For example "git status" gives me:

```
modified:   myproject/.classpath
modified:   myproject/bin/Project.apk  
modified:   myproject/bin/classes.dex
modified:   myproject/bin/resources.ap_
modified:   myproject/lint.xml
```

I am interested whether any of these files (or all of them) could be ignored, because they may cause me trouble when merging later.

Comment: Tip: use android studio

Answer (score 0):

Most of these are auto-generated by eclipse and should be removed from your git index. Since it's already there, you'll need to do `git rm --cached <filename>` for each.

Also, you should use `.gitignore` file in your top-level folder (`myproject`). Add it your your repo with `git add .gitignore`. I have one that contains this for the Eclipse-related ignore:

```
*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/**
tmp/**
tmp/**/*
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath
```

You can view more of such examples in [this repo on GitHub: gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore)

If you are not sure about each of those files, then experiment by moving each one out of the repo and see if anything dies (run your tests/generate code/application).